# Ethernet disconnected trying to fix brightness slider on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, grub2, ethernet, brightness

Running an ROG G15 laptop.

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a dual boot setup with Windows 10 as the other OS. One thing I noticed was that my brightness slider wasn't working, so I looked it up and saw to run `nano /etc/default/grub` in the command line, and add `acpi_backlight=vendor` as a parameter on the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. I then updated Grub with `sudo update-grub`.

After restarting not only did the brightness slider disappear altogether in the settings tab (and the keyboard brightness buttons were not working either) but now my ethernet stopped working too, reporting 'Cable unplugged'.

I went back in and reversed all the changes I made, removing the `acpi_backlight=vendor` parameter and running `sudo update-grub` again. After restarting, the brightness slider returned (but still doesen't work) but the ethernet remains broken.

I'm now mostly concerned on fixing the ethernet, but any solutions to fix the brightness slider are also appreciated.

As a side note, the inside of my laptop makes this weird static/crunchy sound whenever I slide the brightness bar, but again, the brightness stays the same.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.